# Convert hover accordion to onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, onclick, accordion

I have a accordion menu which is developed with pure css3. Currently it is opening the menu when hover on it but I want it to be opened on click. Ho do I achieve this?

One more help. Currently content div is in the right side of the heading but I need that to be opened in the left side.

And content div should have auto width based on the content.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a545y/)

Comment: try to use :active instead of :hover

Comment: Using active is closing the content div when I leave the mouse button. I want the click to be toggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('h3','.horizontalaccordion ul li').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
});​
```

​[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a545y/15/)

Comment: But when I take the cursor out of the div, the content is absconding. Can u please check tat

Comment: `.horizontalaccordion>ul>li.hover>div { display:block; }` instead of `.horizontalaccordion:hover>ul>li.hover>div { display:block; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/a545y/14/

Comment: @Ana Awesome!! Its working. One last help.. How do I take that content panel to open left side??

Comment: @adeneo Yes thanks!!! Can you please help to get that content div to the left side of the menu?

Comment: That's going to take a lot of fiddling with the CSS, and you could just as well start over.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you not just need a click but also would like to close the previously opened panels, then please check out this code:

```
$('h3','.horizontalaccordion ul li').click(function() {
  $('*[class*=hover]').removeClass('hover'); // close all opened tabs
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('hover'); // open the currently clicked one
});​
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/Ra5CT/1/)

I hope that works for you!

Comment: working but Again the same problem. expand one menu take the cursor out of the accordion then it is hiding the content. Pls chk

Comment: I just checked it in Chrome and everything is smooth? Could you please tell me what is your Browser?