# CSS Accordion -> Adding jquery to change "hover" to a toggle but the JS doesn't register?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, accordion

I'm using a pure css accordion, which works as I intended it, with a "hover" function which opens the slides. However I was looking to change this to a toggle so that when you click, it opens, when you click it closes. I found this thread which explained how to do it and provided the JS to do so:

[Convert hover accordion to onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086690/convert-hover-accordion-to-onclick)

However after adding jquery and the script to my html, it doesn't seem to work:

(idk why the title on the accordion doesn't appear where it should, this is only an issue on fiddle, it works as a webpage.)

http://jsfiddle.net/7Q8ea/

```
$('h3','.accordion ul li').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
});
```

I'm guessing the js that I took from the thread above is wrong somehow, but I'm not sure where. I've tried to make sure it's relating to the css I'm using, but I'm not a coder, so I may be missing something obvious.

p.s. the JS above and in the fiddle is taken "as is" from the other thread, I have tried removing the 'h3' etc. to make sure it wasn't that which was causing a problem, but apparently not.

edit: Sorry, forgot to mention, this must be IE8 compatible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Pure CSS accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body id="home">
<ul class="accordion" id="vertical">
<li class="slide-01">
<div>
<h2>Title goes Here</h2>
<br /> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ezY207l.gif" height="125" width="180" /> <taxt>Text here</taxt></div>
</li>
</ul>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script $('h3','.accordion ul li').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit2: Posted my HTML above incase I've made an error here. Maybe. Probably.
Edit3: Okay, seems to be a problem with me having the JS in the body, same if I change it to in the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two problems.  Your jQuery selector was incorrect and you needed to update your `:hover` css selector changing it to a `.hover` class:

New Selector:

```
$('h3, ul.accordion  li').on('click',function() {
//$('h3','.accordion ul li').on('click',function() {
```

New Css

```
/*.accordion:hover li{*/
#vertical .hover li{
    width:100%;
}
/*.accordion:hover{*/
#vertical .hover{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q8ea/5/)

Comment: Thanks boss, will give this a whirl as soon as I can.

Comment: @Jon, I kept that selector as close to the original because you might have some purpose I wasn't aware of, but `.accordion li` would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Daniel, for some reason this works fine in the fiddle, but once I copy the code across to my own files, it stops working. p.s. you changed this in your answer: /*.accordion:hover li{*/
#vertical .hover li{
    width:100%; but not in the actual fiddle, and it still works? p.s. thanks for the console message, lol.

Comment: Marked this as the answer, since it is correct. I think it's just the way I'm trying to use Java that is stopping it working.

Answer (score 0):

The script you need is

```
   $('.accordion li h2').on('click',function() {  
$(this).parents('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
    });
```

You then need to update the css so that it uses the `.hover` instead of `:hover`

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLkaG/